# Wordpress Ads plugin that let me inject ads script anywhere

Tags: wordpress

As the title said, anyone know an ads plugin that can generate some kind of short code from ads script we enter, so I can use it anywhere I like? It's kinda like contact form 7 behavior.

Basically this is what I need:
1. I create the name/category of the ads (or some kind like that)
2. I type the ads script into that name/category.
3. the plugin then generate some kind of short code.
4. I can place those short code anywhere in the theme/file.

Most of ads plugins that I know doesn't freely let me place an ads, usually limited to before post/after post/certain page, etc.

Answer (score 0):

WP Traffic Tools allows for widget placements, inline placements, and custom placements:

http://www.wptraffictools.com/placing-advertisements-in-header-footer-blocks-ad-management-plugin-tip/